# How to remove field from each elements json array postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have table

```
    CREATE TABLE items (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY ,
    data jsonb
);
```

Format of  **data**

```
[
    {
        "id": "d20fe90c-137c-4713-bde1-2d4e75178ad3",
        "text": "text",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "d20fe90c-137c-4713-bde1-2d4e75178ad4",
        ""text": "text",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

How I can remove field **count** from all elements of data json array?

I try

```
UPDATE items
SET data = data #- '{count}';
```

But this query requires index of array element before **count**  as

```
UPDATE items
    SET data = data #- '{0, count}';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no operator or built-in function to do that. Unnest the array and aggregate modified elements in the way like this:

```sql
update items t
set data = (
    select jsonb_agg(elem- 'count')
    from items
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(data) as arr(elem)
    where id = t.id)
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b15346c7168a46cd87c955f75fa81df)